# In Perl, why is a utf-8 string printed differently when split into characters?

Tags: string, perl, unicode, utf-8, language-lawyer

A specially constructed string is printed differently when I use

```
print $b;
```

or

```
print for split //, $b;
```

A minimal example is:

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Encode;

my $b = decode 'utf8', "\x{C3}\x{A1}\x{E2}\x{80}\x{93}\x{C3}\x{A1}"; # 'á–á' in Unicode;

print $b, "\n";
print for split //, $b
```

The output on the console screen (I think I use cp860) is:

```
Wide character in print at xx.pl line 9.
├íÔÇô├í
Wide character in print at xx.pl line 10.
ßÔÇôß
```

or in hex:

```
C3 A1 E2 80 93 C3 A1 
E1 E2 80 93 E1
```

(separated by `0D 0A` of course, i.e., `\r\n`).

The question is WHY is the character rendered differently?

Surprisingly, the effect disappears without the em-dash. The effect is seen for longer strings, as the following example shows.

For the string 'Él es mi tío Toño –Antonio Pérez' (typed as Unicode in the program; note that the two lines are different!):

```
Wide character in print at xx.pl line 14.
├ël es mi t├¡o To├▒o ÔÇôAntonio P├®rez
Wide character in print at xx.pl line 15.
╔l es mi tÝo To±o ÔÇôAntonio PÚrez
```

However, for the string 'Él es mi tío Toño, Antonio Pérez':

```
╔l es mi tÝo To±o, Antonio PÚrez
╔l es mi tÝo To±o, Antonio PÚrez
```

nothing bad happens, and the two lines are rendered in the same way. The only difference is the presence of an en-dash `–`, i.e., `'\x{E2}\x{80}\x{93}'`!

Also, `print join '', split //, $b;` gives the same result as `print $b;` but different from `print for split //, $b;`.

If I add `binmode STDOUT, 'utf8';`, then both outputs are `ÔÇô├í` = E2 80 93 C3 A1.

So my question is not exactly about how to avoid it, but about why this happens: why does the same string behave differently when split?

Apparently in both cases the `utf8` flag is on. Here is a more detailed program that shows more information about both strings: `$a` before `decode` and `$b` after `decode`:

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

use Encode;

my $a = "\x{C3}\x{A1}\x{E2}\x{80}\x{93}\x{C3}\x{A1}"; # 'á–á' in Unicode;
my $b = decode 'utf8', $a;

say '------- length and utf8 ---------';
say "Length (a)=", length $a, ", is_uft8(a)=", (Encode::is_utf8 ($a) // 'no'), ".";
say "Length (b)=", length $b, ", is_uft8(b)=", (Encode::is_utf8 ($b) // 'no'), ".";
say '------- as a variable---------';
say "a: $a";
say "b: $b", ' <== *** WHY?! ***';
say '------- split ---------';
print "a: "; print for split //, $a; say '';
print "b: "; print for split //, $b; say ' <== *** DIFFERENT! ***';
say '------- split with spaces ---------';
print "a: "; print "[$_] " for split //, $a; say '';
print "b: "; print "[$_] " for split //, $b; say '';
say '------- split with properties ---------';
print "a: "; print "[$_ is_utf=" . Encode::is_utf8 ($_) . " length=" . length ($_) . "] " for split //, $a; say '';
print "b: "; print "[$_ is_utf=" . Encode::is_utf8 ($_) . " length=" . length ($_) . "] " for split //, $b; say '';
say '------- ord() ---------';
print "a: "; print ord, " " for split //, $a; say '';
print "b: "; print ord, " " for split //, $b; say '';
```

and here is its output on the console:

```
------- length and utf8 ---------
Length (a)=7, is_uft8(a)=.
Length (b)=3, is_uft8(b)=1.
------- as a variable---------
a: ├íÔÇô├í
Wide character in say at x.pl line 16.
b: ├íÔÇô├í <== *** WHY?! ***
------- split ---------
a: ├íÔÇô├í
Wide character in print at x.pl line 19.
b: ßÔÇôß <== *** DIFFERENT! ***
------- split with spaces ---------
a: [├] [í] [Ô] [Ç] [ô] [├] [í]
Wide character in print at x.pl line 22.
b: [ß] [ÔÇô] [ß]
------- split with properties ---------
a: [├ is_utf= length=1] [í is_utf= length=1] [Ô is_utf= length=1] [Ç is_utf= length=1] [ô is_utf= length=1] [├ is_utf= length=1] [í is_utf= length=1]
Wide character in print at x.pl line 25.
b: [ß is_utf=1 length=1] [ÔÇô is_utf=1 length=1] [ß is_utf=1 length=1]
------- ord() ---------
a: 195 161 226 128 147 195 161
b: 225 8211 225
```

Comment: Please avoid using `my $a` and `my $b`. It can mess up `sort` and some commonly used library subs.

Comment: Yes, right! I used them just for ease of reading :-) In a real program must not be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is whether the string being printed contains any characters >255. `print` only knows you did something wrong in that situation<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

Given a handle with no `:encoding`, `print` expects a string of bytes (string of characters ≤255).

When it doesn't receive bytes (the string contains characters >255), it notifies you of the error ("wide character") and guesses that you meant to encode the string using UTF-8.

You can think of `print` on a handle with no `:encoding` as doing the following:

```
if ($s =~ /[^\x00-\xFF]/) {
   warn("Wide character");
   utf8::encode($s);
}
```

---

```
my $b = decode 'utf8', "\x{C3}\x{A1}\x{E2}\x{80}\x{93}\x{C3}\x{A1}";
```

is the same as

```
my $b = "\xE1\x{2013}\xE1";
```

As such, you are doing

```
print "\xE1\x{2013}\xE1";
print "\xE1";
print "\x{2013}";
print "\xE1";
```

1. ```
   print "\xE1\x{2013}\xE1";   # Wide char! C3 A1 E2 80 93 C3 A1
   ```

   Perl notices you forgot to encode, warns you, and prints the string encoded using UTF-8.
2. ```
   print "\xE1";               # E1
   ```

   Perl has no way of knowing you forgot to encode, so it prints what you asked it to print.
3. ```
   print "\x{2013}";           # Wide char! E2 80 93
   ```

   Perl notices you forgot to encode, warns you, and prints the string encoded using UTF-8.

---

Footnotes

1. The choice of storage format (as returned by `is_utf8`) should never have an effect. `print` is correctly unaffected by it.

   ```
   utf8::downgrade( my $d = chr(0xE1) );  print($d);  # UTF8=0 prints E1
   utf8::upgrade(   my $u = chr(0xE1) );  print($u);  # UTF8=1 prints E1
   ```

Comment: Aha, now I understand! Very simple: `print` interprets the entire string as `utf8` if the string contains at least one character above the ASCII range. When I split the string, then `print` interprets as utf8 only those individual characters (1-character strings) that are above the ASCII range and leaves others interpreted as ASCII.

Comment: `print` interprets the whole string as **Unicode Code Points needing encoding** if the string contains at least one character above **255**. (UTF-8 is what it ends with; not what it starts with. The ASCII encodings only have 128 characters, and `print` doesn't assume the characters are text like the mention of ASCII suggests.)

Comment: Had to read this a few 100 times before I understood what you meant. By default, perl won't print out any code points > 255, so it converts the entire string BACK into bytes (code points <= 255) that it CAN print. I think it would make sense to just print the code points as they are. In the example, he knows he decoded the bytes already, yet perl assumes the exact opposite? Either printing ?s or error out and refusing to print anything I think would be better. "Your string contains chars that I can't print so I cannot process the request". I dont see where that auto-encoding would be useful.

Comment: Re "By default, perl won't print out any code points > 255", Correct. It can't. Files can only contain bytes. Anything other than bytes needs to be converted to byte. `:encoding` tells Perl how to do that.

Comment: Re "I think it would make sense to just print the code points as they are." That makes no sense. 0x2660 cannot be placed in a file.

Comment: Re "In the example, he knows he decoded the bytes already, yet perl assumes the exact opposite?" Perl has no way of knowing the string is decoded code points.

Comment: Re "Either printing ?s or error out and refusing to print anything I think would be better.", It gives a warning you can make fatal.